# How do I render a ViewPage to a string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have tried to implement simple ViewPage caching with ASP.NET MVC, however I cannot get the page to render correctly into a custom HtmlTextWriter when it has a master page.

I have tried overriding Render. If I simply call the base implementation, then everything renders correctly. If I render to my own writer and then write that string, then the page contents get scrambled.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class CachedViewPage
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage

Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    'MyBase.Render(writer)
    'Return

    Dim stringView As String
    Using sw As New StringWriter
        Using w As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            MyBase.Render(w)
        End Using
        stringView = sw.ToString()
    End Using
    writer.Write(stringView)
End Sub

End Class
```

It would seem that there is a tie between the MasterPage, the ViewPage, and the HtmlTextWriter.

How should I properly render this ViewPage to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of the built in caching that is provided by ASP.NET MVC?  It may be more appropriate to use what is provided by the framework.

Here is a great overview; [Donut Caching in ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

As far as I know it is not possible to get the output of the view as a string (maybe if you override the Render in the master page?) without developing or using an alternative view engine.

There are some alternative view engines available in [MVC Contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Documentation&referringTitle=Home) if you are interested in taking a look.